# Let $V$ and $W$ be n-dimensional vector spaces, and let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear mapping.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ and $W$ be n-dimensional vector spaces, and let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear mapping. Suppose $\beta$ is a basis for $V$. Prove $T$ is an isomorphism if and only if $T(\beta)$ is a basis for $W$.

Let $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be basis for $V$ and $W$ respectively. $\beta = \{v_1,v_2,...v_n\}$, and let $\gamma=\{w_1,w_2,...w_n\}$. Since $T$ is an isomorphism, $T(\beta)$={$T(v_1), T(v_2), T(v_3),..., T(v_n)$} Since T is surjective, $T(\beta)$=W. Hence $T(\beta)$ is a basis for $W$.

Can someone check my forward proof?

Comment: @xyz12345 $W$ is a vector space, not a vector which can be written as a linear combination. If $\beta = \{ v_1,\dots,v_n \}$ then $T(\beta) = \{ T(v_1),\dots,T(v_n)\}$. So, since there are $n$ vectors in $T(\beta)$, it suffices to show that it is linearly independent.

Comment: Would you please specify even more?

Comment: @Azif00 Based on your suggestion let me fix it

Comment: @Azif00 How about now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T(\beta)$ is not equal to $W$, the span is it. If $w\in W$, since $T$ is surjective, there exists $v\in V$ such that $w  = T(v)$, and since $\beta$ is a basis for $V$, $v$ can be written as a linear combination of $v_1,\dots,v_n$. Use this to show that $w$ can be written as a linear combination of $T(v_1),\dots,T(v_n)$.